# Making changes to edits

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, suggested-edit-bans

Editing a question to make it clearer is always a good way to improve the environment of this community. But I found that, while some mistakes are made throughout editing the post, it seems like we cannot make further changes to it, and even I could not delete it. It seems like a kinds of embarrassing to see the mistake laying on the "edits" column.

And it becomes more embarrassing particularly when the edit is accepted.

Is it a problem to be solved?

Comment: I've changed the tags of your question; for a [feature-request], you need to post a suggested solution to the proposed problem.

Comment: @Glorfindel I understood the post as proposing the feature "retract suggested edit" (or also "modify"), that is a user that realizes they made an error in their suggested edit could withdraw it (or correct).

Comment: Could be – I added another paragraph to my answer. It would help if the OP let us know what he/she really meant.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct that you can't suggest an edit to a post while there's another one pending. That would make reviewing a bit awkward; if both edits are approved, what would the final result be? Users with >2k reputation who are [reviewing](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) the suggested edits can choose to *improve* edits which need more fixing, and also *reject* & edit posts immediately.

You actually *can* improve your own suggested edit while it's being reviewed. You cannot retract it.

If this happens to your *own* post, you also have a shot at reviewing the suggested edit (even if you don't have 2k reputation), or to [roll it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/295232) if it had already been approved.

Users who make too many bad edits will eventually be banned (temporarily) from suggesting edits. The formula for this is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/295232). The system looks at the number of rejected and approved edits in the past seven days; the threshold for the ban is

$$\text{# rejects} - \frac{\text{# approvals}}{3} >= 5$$

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant that the Edit "comment" cannot be edited?  I've observed that when I improve an Edit (even one of my own) the submitted Comment that goes with the Edit cannot be revised.  It's not much of a problem of course.